# Retrieve strong name of .NET assembly in Inno Setup

Tags: .net, inno-setup, .net-assembly, pascalscript, strongname

I need to install these some DLL files to the GAC.

I use preprocessor to generate `[Files]` section entries for these DLLs. And I need to provide a value for the `StrongAssemblyName` parameter.

So question

1. Can I automatically retrieve the `StrongAssemblyName` of a DLL from a Pascal Script?
2. If not, can one create a dictionary so I could look up in the dictionary using the assembly name as key, and then have hardcoded value strings that would get used when automatically building up the line
   `Source: path; DestDir`

I would prefer the first solution, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think, there's a native way to retrieve a strong name in Inno Setup Pascal Script.

But, you can use a simple PowerShell command to retrieve the strong name.

```powershell
([Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom('My.dll')).FullName
```

Combining these two questions:

- [How can I see the strong name of my assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17375759/850848#17375848)
- [How to get an output of an Exec'ed program in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1136770/850848)

you get a code like:

```pascal
function GetAssemblyStrongName(FileName: string): string;
var
  TmpFileName: string;
  Args: string;
  StrongName: AnsiString;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  TmpFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\strong_name.txt';
  Args :=
    Format('-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "Set-Content -Path "%s" -NoNewline ' +
           '-Value ([Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(''%s'')).FullName"', [
           TmpFileName, FileName]);
  if (not Exec('powershell.exe', Args, '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)) or
     (ResultCode <> 0) or
     (not LoadStringFromFile(TmpFileName, StrongName)) then
  begin
    RaiseException(Format('Error retrieving strong name of "%s"', [FileName]));
  end;

  Result := StrongName;
  DeleteFile(TmpFileName);
end;
```

---

Though actually, you cannot use Pascal Scripting, as you need the strong name on compile-time, and the Pascal Scripting is executed on install-time only. In some cases, you can use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants), but it's not supported in the [`StrongAssemblyName` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=StrongAssemblyName).

So again, you have to use a [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/).

The Pascal Script code translates to the preprocessor like:

```
#define GetAssemblyStrongName(FileName) \
  Local[0] = AddBackslash(GetEnv("TEMP")) + "strong_name.txt", \
  Local[1] = \
    "-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command """ + \
    "Set-Content -Path '" + Local[0] + "' -NoNewline -Value " + \
    "([Reflection.Assembly]::ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom('" + FileName + "')).FullName" + \
    """", \
  Exec("powershell.exe", Local[1], SourcePath, , SW_HIDE), \
  Local[2] = FileOpen(Local[0]), \
  Local[3] = FileRead(Local[2]), \
  FileClose(Local[2]), \
  DeleteFileNow(Local[0]), \
  Local[3]
```

You can use it in the `StrongAssemblyName` parameter like:

```
[Files]
Source: "My.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
  StrongAssemblyName: "{#GetAssemblyStrongName('My.dll')}"
```

Which gets preprocessed to something like:

```
[Files]
Source: "My.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
  StrongAssemblyName: "My, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2271ec4a3c56d0bf"
```

---

Though, as you [generate the `[Files]` section completely by a preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45969182/850848), your current code from your comment will now work, as the syntax, that you have used, actually calls `GetAssemblyStrongName` preprocessor macro and not `GetAssemblyStrongName` Pascal Script function.

Note that the macro above uses C-style strings, so it has to be *outside* the Pascal-style `pragma` directives:

```
; here

#pragma parseroption -p-

; not here

#pragma parseroption -p+

; or here
```